# XMLSlurper inside Groovy Script Not Working for a simple XML

Tags: java, groovy, xmlslurper

I am trying to parse an XML using Groovy Script's XMLSlurper plugin.
I need to read the value in **d:editStatus** element.

```
import groovy.xml.*;
def myxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">' +
    '<entry>' +
        '<content type="application/xml">' +
            '<m:properties>' +
                '<d:key>JobApplication/applicationId=94319</d:key>' +
                '<d:status>OK</d:status>' +
                '<d:editStatus>UPDATED</d:editStatus>' +
                '<d:message>Application has been updated successfully</d:message>' +
                '<d:index m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:index>' +
                '<d:httpCode m:type="Edm.Int32">204</d:httpCode>' +
                '<d:inlineResults m:type="Bag(SFOData.UpsertResult)"></d:inlineResults>' +
            '</m:properties>' +
        '</content>' +
    '</entry>' +
    '</feed>'


def mystatus = new XmlSlurper().parseText(myxml)

println mystatus
```

Here, the output should have showed the object form of the xml but it gives me the following output

```
JobApplication/applicationId=94319OKUPDATEDApplication has been updated successfully0204
```

It is very wierd as i cannot see any elements, it is concatenating all the values and showing as output. I cannot fetch a single element.

Comment: println myxml.entry.content.properties.editStatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing out the value of your [GPathResult](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html) will by default print out all of the values of its nodes.

To extract the values of individual nodes:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def myxml = '''
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
        <entry>
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                    <d:key>JobApplication/applicationId=94319</d:key>
                    <d:status>OK</d:status>
                    <d:editStatus>UPDATED</d:editStatus>
                    <d:message>Application has been updated successfully</d:message>
                    <d:index m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:index>
                    <d:httpCode m:type="Edm.Int32">204</d:httpCode>
                    <d:inlineResults m:type="Bag(SFOData.UpsertResult)"></d:inlineResults>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
        </entry>
    </feed>
'''


def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(myxml)

println "key: ${xml.entry.content.properties.key}"
println "status: ${xml.entry.content.properties.status}"
println "editStatus: ${xml.entry.content.properties.editStatus}"
println "message: ${xml.entry.content.properties.message}"
println "index: ${xml.entry.content.properties.index}"
println "httpCode: ${xml.entry.content.properties.httpCode}"
println "inlineResults: ${xml.entry.content.properties.inlineResults}"
```

You can also extract the value of a node attribute using @

```
println xml.entry.content.@type
```

Comment: yes it works perfectly. Thanks for the useful attribute tip